# Cookie blocker for social networks like Facebook & Twitter and custom entries

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

Is there any Chrome based cookie blocker that will prevent cookies from being written to your browser for things like Facebook and Twitter?

So many sites use Facebook that they sort of invade your privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly cookie blocker, but achieves what you need: [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/). It blocks all sorts of social sites buttons (among other things) that are placed on third-party sites. By doing that it doesn't allow cookies from these social sites to be set (obviously before using it you may want to delete any such existing cookies, if any)

Alternatively, in Chrome you can go to Settings, then Show advanced settings, then in Privacy choose Content settings and then Cookies and select `Keep cookies and site data by default until you quit your browser`. That would interfere with cookies that you may want to keep, so you may need to use also `Make exceptions for cookies from specific websites or domains`